# Intelli j Java fx Artifacts jar doesnt work

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, javafx, pie-chart

Im currently working on a projekt were i have made some JFX Piecharts and integrating them with Swing Jpanels.

Im using Intelli j Idea and when i try to run the code using intelli j it works fine. But when i make a jar file out of it using the artifacts option, it bugs.

what happens is that it cant execute the piechart.class which is using JFX. så the application stops.

what the piechart class does is that it creates a piechart using JFX and by using JFXPanel i import it to a Swing JPanel.
chart->JFXPanel->Jpanel->display panel

any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is the error

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at ov_panel.setupcharts(ov_panel.java:142)
    at ov_panel.<init>(ov_panel.java:37)
    at userpanel.<init>(userpanel.java:52)
    at panels.swap(panels.java:33)
    at login.pass_check(login.java:96)
    at login$2.keyPressed(login.java:125)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2828)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Can you run try to run the jar through terminal/command and trace the error ? The way jar is made must be a problem, but we cant be sure unless we trace the error/log

Comment: Runned it through terminal and editet the original post with the error i got. appreciate the help :)

Comment: Can you tell us how you're running the jar? It looks like you've not set up your classpath correctly, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: This error is because your `jfxrt.jar` is not picked by your jar/set in classpath. Try using one of the deployment methods suggested by [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) instead of using IntelliJ to create the jar !